# Diagnosing mystery Implicit references in Addressables

Tags: unity, addressable

I am working on a game with a modest number of assets where the majority of the game's assets are not managed through Addressables, but some rarely used tutorial UI prefabs will be managed through Addressables.

In the Analyze window, if I run the "Bundle Layout Preview" analyzer, it's showing hundreds of implicit references to various assets, including many that seem mysterious to me. I've tried removing all of the addressable UI prefabs but one to try to narrow down where these mystery implicit references are coming from, but it seems like any of the UI prefabs will create all of these implicit references.

Is there a way to break down the implicit references in more detail and see the path that the analyzer took to get to a particular implicit reference?